# MAUI | Trying to access user information after user login

Tags: c#, sql, .net, data-binding, maui

I am new at .NET MAUI or .NET

I am trying to access information from the database after logging in. The main code of login:
I have tried and googled a lot; however, I did not find any way.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using LoginMAUI.Models;
using LoginMAUI.View;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LoginMAUI.ViewModel;

public partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    readonly Database db = new Database();
    User user = new User();

    [ObservableProperty]
    string email;
    [ObservableProperty]
    string password;

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Login()
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;

        con = new SqlConnection(
            $"Data Source={db.DatabaseServer};" +
            $"Initial Catalog={db.databaseName};" +
            $"User Id={db.DatabaseUser};" +
            $"Password={db.databasePass};" +
            $"TrustServerCertificate=True"); ; ;
        try 
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM WeWillDoIt.accounts where email='" + email + "' AND password='" + password + "'";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                user.email = dr["email"].ToString();
                user.password = dr["password"].ToString();
                user.username = dr["username"].ToString();
                user.name = dr["name"].ToString();
                user.lastname = dr["surname"].ToString();
                user.country = dr["country"].ToString();
                user.city = dr["city"].ToString();
                user.postcode = dr["postcode"].ToString();
                user.created = dr["created"].ToString();

                User userList = new User
                {
                    email = dr["email"].ToString(),
                    password = dr["password"].ToString(),
                    username = dr["username"].ToString(),
                    name = dr["name"].ToString(),
                    lastname = dr["surname"].ToString(),
                    country = dr["country"].ToString(),
                    city = dr["city"].ToString(),
                    postcode = dr["postcode"].ToString(),
                    created = dr["created"].ToString()
                };

                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Dashboard)}?List={userList}");

            }
            else
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Login Unsuccessful!", "Invalid Email: " + email + " | Or Password : " + password, "Ok");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Database!", "Error code: " + ex, "Ok");
        }
    }


[RelayCommand]
    async Task Register()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(RegisterPage));
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace LoginMAUI.Models;

public partial class User : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string lastname;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string email;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string username;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string password;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string number;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string country;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string city;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string postcode;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string created;

    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

Dashboard ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using LoginMAUI.Models;
using LoginMAUI.View;

namespace LoginMAUI.ViewModel;

[QueryProperty(nameof(LoginPage), nameof(LoginPage))]
public partial class DashboardViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    static UserLogin userList;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string username = "Username: " + userList.username;

}
```

Dashboard page:

```
public partial class Dashboard : ContentPage
{
    UserLogin userLogin;
    User user;
    public Dashboard(DashboardViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

I tried to make user models as static, however this error shows: Severity
Error   CS1914  Static field or property 'User.name' cannot be assigned in an object initializer    LoginMAUI

I tried to make the property on the Dashboard static, but that would not allow as well.

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Have you searched on CS1914?  This is a C# compiler error, nothing specific to MAUI

Comment: On DashBoard:

If i make: UserLogin userList;
CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'DashboardViewModel.userList'

However, if i make it Static: static UserLogin userList;
CS0649 Field 'DashboardViewModel.userList' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

When i try to debug it: UserList is not null

Comment: Initialize it in the VM constructor

Comment: Hi sorry i forgot to add it on the post: Its already there on the code

Comment: No, userList needs to be initialized

Comment: Can you please provide with an example how to it without getting Null?

Comment: Add a constructor to your VM and initialize userList in it.  It is null because you are not assigning any value to it.

Comment: Can solve it. 

    [ObservableProperty]
    string username = "Username ";

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        UserLogin userLogin;
    }

Is it not supposed to store user information to User class? Why is it null? When i debug it i can see that information is passed to User, however after i move to the Dashboard page they go to null.

Comment: Please read the docs on passing data when navigating.  You are not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to the docs on [passing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data) when navigating.  You are not doing it correctly

to pass an object when navigating, do this

```
var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "List", userList }
};

await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Dashboard)}", navigationParameter);
```

then in the page or VM that you are navigating to

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(UserList), "List")]
public partial class DashboardViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    UserLogin userList;
}
```